# Do we have any open source tool which allow generation of excel file from database table?

Tags: excel, oracle10g

Do we have any open source tool which allow generation of excel file from database table? Actually we don't have comments in our database tables, I would be great if i can take the table def in excel file, update the comments and execute the scripts back in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what [db design excel](http://dbdesignexcel.sourceforge.net) does.

Comment: It looks quite interesting. Will definitely try this!

Comment: Wow,i just used it and great.
this is what i was exactly looking for.
Cool...a great time saviour.